# import matlab.engine hangs (R2016a)

Tags: matlab, python-2.7, matlab-engine

I'm trying to use the Matlab Engine API for Python and I installed using standard procedure on Matlab's site. 
However, it takes forever and doesn't show any prompts. 
Until I manually break and exit.

Any installation issues that I'm missing here? 
I don't get an error message either.
The "unknown error" that is displayed is after I provide a  keyboard interrupt.

[image: screenshot to show where python hangs and I break]

Comment: Do you have MATLAB installed?

Comment: @Suever, yes. Matlab R2016a. And I ran the setup.py install script under Matlab\extern\engines\python

Comment: I have the same problem right now, despite having made this work previously on the same machine.

Comment: Logging out and logging in again fixed my problem on Linux...